# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list Error

Tags: python, string

**Code**

```
text = ["300000", "300001", "500000", "500001"]
cnt = 0
for line in f:
    if text in line:
        print(line.strip())
        cnt += 1
if cnt:
    print(cnt, "count")
else:
    print(text, "No data.")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/users/PycharmProjects/Mining/Test Folder/Test2.py", line 10, in <module>
    if text in line:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Why this error occurs?

Comment: What is `f` here?

Comment: Because `line` is a string object and `text` is a list object, You are checking whether string contains list.

Comment: f means nothing....

Comment: What do you want to do with above code ? What is the logic youare trying to implement.

Comment: There is a lot of data in the text file.
When the data is loaded, if any of the four data I wrote matches, it show all the matching sentences.

Comment: Like the error explains, 'in' needs a string object on the left hand side whereas in your code, you have used ```text``` which is a list.

Comment: If I change the position of text and line, the data not displayed that i want. Only["300000", "300001", "500000", "500001"] displayed.

Comment: You have to tell us what your file looks like so we know what you are trying to do. Are you trying to figure out if each line matches one of those 4 strings?

Comment: Yes, That's it.

Comment: The first solution I provided in my answer will do that then

Comment: Thank you all. It was solved thanks to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` keyword is used to check if a certain value is inside a collection.

If you want to know if `line` is in the list `text`, switch your operands:

```
text = ["300000", "300001", "500000", "500001"]
cnt = 0
for line in f:
    if line in text: 
        print(line.strip())
```

If you want to know if any of the strings in the list `text` is inside/a substring of `line`:

```
text = ["300000", "300001", "500000", "500001"]
cnt = 0
for line in f:
    if any([i in line for i in text]): 
        print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Great to hear. If you can mark the question as resolved, it would be greatly appreciated. @이현규

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand how 'in' works in python. 
Example: 
`> "abc" in ["pqr", "xyz", "abc"]` 
`True` 
Here I am testing if string "abc" exist in the list mentioned on the right side of 'in' which is ["pqr", "xyz", "abc"]

But you are checking for the existence of a list (`text` in your code) inside another list (`line` in your code).
Hence, as the error says 'in requires string as left operand' but you supplied a list.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use comments to clarify things.

Comment: Hello @PrashantKumar, The question is `Why this error occurs?` and I answered that, explaining why that error occurs. Can you please let me know why this is not the answer